# Firebase how to delete related data

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im thinking to use firebase and before that I'd like to know some firebase stuff. Let's say I have group and users related to that group example:

```
{
  "users":{
    "user1":{
        "username":"john",
        "full_name":"John Vincent",
        "created_at":"9th Feb 2015",
        "groups":{
            "group1":true,
            "group3":true
        }
        "last_logins":...
    },
    "user2": ...,
    "user3": ...
  }
  "groups": {
     "group1"{
        "group_name":"Administrators",
        "group_description":"Users who can do anything!",
        "no_of_users":2,
        "members":{
            "user1":true,
            "user3":true
        }
      },
     "group2"{
        "group_name":"Moderators",
        "group_description":"Users who can only moderate!",
        "no_of_users":1,
        "members":{
            "user2":true
        }
      }
   }
 }
```

And I was wondering is it possible to delete related user to groups. Lets say if I delete `Group2` I'd like to delete related users which is `user2` on this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. To achieve this, you need to query your database for finding the users that corespond to a particular group which you want to delete. Having those users `names` or `id's` will allow you delete the desired users.

To delete a single user, get the root reference of your Firebase database and then use remove function on the reference of those particular users.

```
Firebase root -> child("users") -> child("user1") -> remove function
```

In the end, just delete the entire group using the reference of the particular group.

```
Firebase root -> child("groups") -> child("group1") -> remove function
```

Remember, the flow is as follows:

> Find the users coreponding to a particular group -> add the user names or users id to a list -> use remove function on the users reference according to the user names or ids from the list -> use remove function on the group reference to delete the particular group.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Non-SQL databases like Firebase use JSON. You will have to read the JSON to see which users are part of Group 2 before you delete Group 2. Then you'll need to delete those users 1st. After they are deleted, then you could delete Group 2.

If you want to setup a trigger, you could have it call a function that would automatically do some of the work for you. Check out these Firebase trigger links for details on how to setup triggers:

1. [Trigger a function with an HTTP request](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events)
2. [Trigger a database function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#trigger_a_database_function)